# Linux Clipboard Manager that allows push _and_ pop

Tags: linux, clipboard

Clipboard managers obviously allow users to "push" snippets onto a stack.  The problem is that to paste them we usually have to go to a menu and choose which one we want.  Often, I need to copy multiple snippets from one window, and then paste them into another.  For that operation, I'd like to be able to pop snippets, one by one, off the stack.

[Diodon](https://github.com/diodon-dev/diodon) had a [plugin](https://github.com/RedHatter/diodon-plugins) to do this, but it's long defunct.

I'm using linux, and would be happy to hear any suggestions!